# Double index within a noSQL database

Tags: database, concurrency, nosql

I am working on creating a database to store three things. Let's say Experiment, Measure, metadata. The metadata is composed of a set of variable number and type of attributes, thus making the choice of a NoSQL attractive.

I need two simple queries over the database:

1) Give me the metadata of all the experiments with a given value of Measure.
2) Give me the metadata of all the measures for a Experiment.

And my main requirements are:

1) Tons of data. Each Experiment can come with millions of possible measures (and of course the metadata), and I expect tenths of thousands of Experiments.
2) Concurrency. I would like to have fast concurrent read/write because at any given point in time I may be running 10-20 experiments, and they will want to write millions of measures at the same time.

I've tried MongoDB, but it is slow due to the write locks. I would like to have something faster. Additionally, it does not handle well one of my queries, as I basically need two indexes here. I am considering as an alternative Titan, just because it seems natural to think of experiments an measures as nodes, and connect them with edges. Hypertable seems another possibility if I can find a way of doing both queries fast.

There are so many noSQL databases out there that I may be missing the right one for my needs. Suggestions?

Comment: I would just make a comment that there is most likely no silver bullet for your needs. We'd all love a database that can grow infinitely, accept billions of writes and serve billions of reads at the same time with no latency. But reality is we have to compromise at some point. I would spend some time investigating how you can compromise to achieve your goals. Just friendly advice.

Comment: I agree of course that I may be asking for too much. But given that I want simple queries, perhaps there is a specific database that performs better than others in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into NewSQL databases that could fit your needs? I suggest that you take a closer look at Starcounter that is true ACID, no locks on the writes and supports indexing on basic properties as well as combined indexes.

I think a transactional database that is object oriented and memory centric would suit your demands. You can then have different Experiments and Measures that derives the same class and you can select to query each type as well as query the ineherited types separately.

If you do not have more than TB of data you do not need a big data database that you have looked into so far. They are really good at what they do, but I think you should look into the other spectrum of NoSQL databases. When using an in-memory (all writes secured on persistent storage media of course) database that is object oriented you get about 4 times compressions compared to relational databases, so the TB of data would often be enaugh.

It is really hard to find your way around in the jungle of databases today, so I understand the difficulty of finding something that fits your requirements. In your case - my 5 cents on a transactional NoSQL database that is true ACID and with SQL query support!